# Alexa DateSlot Morgen vs. Morgan

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We are building a german alexa skill where one of our intents uses a `DateSlot`. If we ask with the name of a Day (e.g. Dienstag, Mittwoch), Alexa understands our input and correctly call our api with this day. If we ask for `"morgen"` (stands for tommorrow), Alexa understands `"morgan"` and can not map the input to a date and so Alexa asks for a different input.

How can we ensure, that Alexa interprets our voice input as a german word and not as an english word?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I explicit added my question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about German vs. English, but we ran into a similar issue with slot types. We originally did not understand that slot types are not a finite list of inputs, but training values. We ended up using the JaroWinklerDistance method in the natural package. We made a list of out expected slot types to attempting matching against and went with the best match. Our slot types were for car makes, types, and colors. So you can imagine the invalid values we had coming in.

Possibly you can do something similar by making a new intent to capture your known invalid values and do the natural.JaroWinklerDistance matching. You would need to add more utterances to match your DateSlot utterances which expect another slot with 'morgen' and other values you incorrectly receive. Then, with you intent handing, detect the string value and match through your known list of values. You can always fail out if something entirely unexpected happens, as it does now when you receive 'morgan'. We had to play with the threshold for the best match to determine if we used it or not.

Or, you can build up a list of items you constantly get and map them to valid values. We also had a slot that expected 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. During development we were getting too, four, two, to, etc... We ended up mapping these known values in a list and translating them to what we expected. For this situation we had a fairly limited list of values we had to translate for, but it worked well.